# How to get <td> elements from Nokogiri element?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my rb file:

```
    require "open-uri"
        require "nokogiri"


        url = "http://www.languagedaily.com/learn-german/vocabulary/common-german-words"
        html = open(url)
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

        row = doc.css("tr")
     row.each do |cell|
        puts cell
     end
```

The separate element looks like:

```
   <tr class="rowA">
<td class="number">49.</td>
<td class="bigLetter">kann</td>
<td>(I) can, am able to (he/she/it) can (1st- and 3-rd person singular present of "können")</td>
<td>verb</td>
</tr>
```

I need to get first three td's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just continue using `css`

```
row.css("td").take(3).each{}
```